# Why datatype of vectors are declared within angle brackets in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I am confused about declaring of datatype in C++. Generally, it is written like - `int a;` Meaning that variable a is integer data type. But for vector type of arrays, it is written as -  `vector<integer> vectorname;` Why is this necessary? Is it because vector is like a class in C++ ? I have checked following links which discussed somewhat related topic:

- [Reason for using non-type template parameter instead of regular parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395700/reason-for-using-non-type-template-parameter-instead-of-regular-parameter)
- [What is angle brackets for argument values, and what is it used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202200/what-is-angle-brackets-for-argument-values-and-what-is-it-used-for)

These links discuss the utility of angle brackets for template declaration, which I understand and know. I could not get the answer to the question as to why these are necessary for vectors.

Comment: `std::vector` is a class template. The thing in angle brackets is its parameter. You say you understand and know this, so what again is unclear?

Comment: I think you need to begin reading [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part).

Comment: "Why is this necessary?" Well maybe it isnt't but nobody knows yet. How would you write it without the angle brackets?

Comment: A `std::vector` is like any other *container*; it needs a template argument to specify the type of its elements.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik : I know this is used for templates for defining generic datatypes in angle brackets. Whenever, any value is passed compiler, automatically assigns a data type based on the value passed to the template function. This is very different from the characteristic of vector. We are declaring a fixed data type - integer/double/float, then why make it as a template at all? It could have been designed and hence declared just like an array. I am sure there is some reason to it, and that is what I want to understand.

Comment: `why make it as a template at all?` What would you make it instead? Go ahead, try writing a container class that can be used to store `int`s sometimes and `double`s other times.

Comment: @BatCoder: Thanks for sharing that link. I read it and gained many new concepts about usage of templates, particularly essence of angle brackets. Still, it does not explain why certain commands like that of "Vector" need angle brackets for the declaration ? Probably if the answer is that vector is a class template, then my question is why it is designed at all like a class template which necessitates adding a different declaration syntax? What is the advantage is being added by making "vector" like a class template and not just a variable (say 'a') which is declared like - int a; or double a;

Comment: @AGOEL, so that the compiler can deduce that it is a template type (and not a normal data type).

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you see something like `<T>` in C++, that's a template.  And a template is like a "recipe" which can be used to make another piece of code, at compile time.  Or to put it another way, the `T` (which is often a type, like `int` or `string`) is just a parameter, the same as how functions in C or any other language have parameters.  But in C++ these parameters are evaluated at compile time, so they cost nothing to execute once the program is built.

Comment: John, thanks for a simplified response. Then do we not need a similar syntax of declaration for arrays because vectors are templates and arrays are not? If yes, then to know all such pre-defined templates is there any list I can refer to ?

Comment: @AGOEL _"is there any list I can refer to ?"_ [Sure](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Comment: @AGOEL: There actually is a similar syntax for arrays in C++: `std::array<int, 10> arr;`.  Note that the `10` is used at compile time to do what C does when you say `int arr[10];`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Thanks for sharing that. Could you shed some light on when to prefer the declaration syntax you mentioned (using the angle brackets) versus the syntax:  int a[10]; in C++ ? If there is something I should read first, please let me know.

Comment: @AGOEL: You should use `std::array<int, 10> arr;` in C++.  It's more featureful than the C style `int arr[10];`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: could you please highlight about the "more featureful" aspect? I fail to comprehend the added functionality/ features it offers in this syntax. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: @AGOEL: `std::array` class template is a wrapper for traditional arrays like `int[]` but it has benefits that you can use member functions along with other STL containers and cannot be decayed into a pointer type, unlike traditional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The type name specified from the class template `std::vector` or other containers will specify what type of data will be used and will then generate a code at compile-time. You should specify the data type to be used inside the angular brackets or the template arguments.

Since CTAD (Class Template Argument Deduction) was introduced in C++ 17 which is the same to function template argument deduction, you are no longer required to specify its type because the compiler will do something about that unless you declare the instance without the initializations.

```cpp
// Before C++ 17:
std::vector<int> vect1 {4, 5, 10, 4, 10}; // ok!
std::vector vect2 {3, 1, 5, 10}; // error: missing template arguments!

// Since C++ 17:
std::vector<int> vect3 {23, 12, 5, 12}; // ok!
std::vector vect4 {4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 10}; // ok!
std::vector vect5; // error: class template argument deduction failed!
std::vector<int> vect5; // ok!
```

The type of `vect4` will be exactly the same to other instances' type which is `std::vector<int>` or internally `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>`